# How to manage the article content in an asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net

I'm planning to create a site for learning technologies, such as codeproject or codeplex. Can you please suggest to me the different ways to manage huge articles?

Answer (score 0):

Look at a content management system, such as SiteFinity: http://www.sitefinity.com/.  There are others, some free.  You can find some on codeplex.com.

HTH.

Comment: Hey thanks. i dont want to use the 3rd party tool even it is free. i like to manage by our self

Comment: A content management system is essentially the functionality you are asking for, if you don't want to download/buy, you have to build it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Check out DotNetNuke CMS too >> http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

And here's a very hot list available of ASP.NET CMS systems:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Microsoft_ASP.NET_2

Comment: Thanks, But i want to manage article by own. I want to know how the people was managed before cms arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to manage articles while building the entire system yourself. Hmm, ok, let me give it a try... here's the short version.

There are several ways you can "store" your articles (content, data, whatever), and the best way to do so is to use a Database. ([SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), [SQLCE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/index.html), [the list goes on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#General_information)).

If you're not sold on the idea of a database, you can use any other type of persistent storage that you like. IE: [XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/), or even flat "[TXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file)" files.

Since you're using ASP.NET you now need to either write your code behind, or some other complied code to access your stored data. You pull it out of the storage and display it on the page/view.

Last but not least, I'd like to give you a suggestion (even though it's not part of your original question). As the other answerers have stated, you should look at a pre-built CMS. If nothing else, to see how it's done (not necessarily to use it as is). My philosophy is quite simple, if you want to be productive in your development, don't bother reinventing the wheel just for the sake of it. If someone else has already build and given away exactly what you need, you should at very least give it a look and use what you can. It will save you piles of time and heartache.

Your question is not vague enough to be closed, but is vague enough that answering all of the nuances could take several thousand lines.

Comment: thanks. i just want to confirm that the way you said was followed in earlier to manage the huge articles

Comment: If you're using a database like SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc. Then the size of the article doesn't matter. They can store whatever size you throw at them. (not that they all have unlimited storage, but I'm pretty sure you don't have a single article that's GB's in size). Express (Free) versions do have a size limit of a few Gigabytes.

Comment: if the content has the picture, how do i need to mange it. please give a idea

Comment: You can either store the binary in the database, but you are better off storing it on the server. For instance, if you use a [WYSIWYG](http://ckeditor.com/) editor, many come with an image uploader. You upload the image to the server, and the WYSIWYG editor links the article `<img src />` to that file.